# Maximum value of $f(x, y, z) = e^{xyz}$ in the domain x+y+z = 3.

Tags: maxima-minima

Need the maximum value of f$(x, y, z) = e^{xyz}$ in the domain $x+y+z = 3$.

Please help me on this, as I could not find how to solve this one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does youtr question mean $x,y, z > 0$? if no, maximum value is infinite

Comment: can you say something to the variables?

Comment: Since the exponential function is monotone increasing, maximizing $f(x,y,z)$ is equivalent to maximizing $xyz$, subject to the restriction $x+y+z = 3$.  As kotomord points out, this cannot be maximized without further restriction on the variables.

Comment: I suppose it means find a local maximum with isolating one variable with x+y+z=3 then you get a function of two variables. It has a local maximum if the derivatives are all zero and the determinant of the hessian is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $x,y,z \ge 0$

$e^{xyz}$ is maximum if $xyz$ is maximum

$AM \ge GM\\
\implies \dfrac{x+y+z}{3} \ge\sqrt[3]{xyz}\\
\implies \sqrt[3]{xyz} \le 1\\
\implies xyz \le 1$

Maximum value of $e^{xyz}=e^{1}=e$

Answer (score -1):

For **e^xyz** the domain is all *(x,y,z)* ,so the domain is ***whole space***

Comment: The question already specified the domain and asked about the maximum value of the function. Typesetting the math in your answer would also help.